# Enabling developer mode in Huawei Mediapad M2 10.0

Tags: tablet, huawei, developer-options

Self explanatory.

Normally Android 5.1.1 allows to tap 7 times on "Build number" field in Settings->Tablet info.

Unfortunately the "Build number" field is absent in my Settings application.

What else can I do? I need to use the developer mode for rooting

Update: here is a screenshot. I have redacted the SN. Locale is IT

[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of Settings -> About? This article suggests there exists Build number: http://reviewroots.com/root-Huawei-MediaPad-M2-10.0-with-or-without-pc

Comment: Related: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7swUjZm7y6c. Screenshot coming

Comment: I have also tried to tap "Custom version" (Versione personalizzata) several times without effect

Answer (score 2):

Needed to tap on the `Serial number` field. **This** is the answer